# Fast generation of matrix for multiple variables that take the same vector of values

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have 6 variables, each variable takes every value in [1,2,3,4]. So the total combination is 4^6. I want a matrix as follows,

111111
111112
111113
111114
111121
...
444444

I know I can just use 6 **for loops** to do this. Look for a better way to generate this.

Comment: @Cris I don't think that's the best dup since in this question all of the variables have the same range. This could be solved by iterating over `value` in `dec2base(value, "1234", 6)`.

Comment: Oops, Octave only. For MATLAB use `dec2base(value, 4, 6)` and then adjust the char to int conversion by 1.

Comment: @beaker I found another Q&A that has the `dec2base` solution. Thanks!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Cool. Sometimes one-liners obfuscate, sometimes they clarify. In this case, to me it's clearer to do a base conversion, but that may just be me. For such a small number of values pretty much any reasonable approach will be fast enough.

Comment: @beaker Great. Base change is what I was looking for!